# Проблема с чтением из файла fscanf

Tags: c, файлы, c++

Привет всем написал кое какой  код на `cudaC/C++`, написал функции по генерированию и записи матрицы в файл, но функция для чтения `fscanf()` из функции "`void read_matrix_from_file`" как я полагаю работает не правильно, она находится в файле `genAndRead.cpp`. ниже приведу код функций:

```
genAndRead.h

#ifndef GEN_AND_READ
#define GEN_AND_READ
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

(......)
void read_matrix_from_file(int**, int**, float**, int*, int*);
    (......)

#ifdef __cplusplus
} //end extern "C"
#endif

#endif
```

genAndRead.cpp:

```
(.......)

extern "C" {

(.......)

void read_matrix_from_file(int** I, int** J, float** val, int* N, int* nz)
{
FILE* f;
 f = fopen("sparse_matrix", "r");
if((f = fopen("sparse_matrix", "r"))==NULL)
{
puts ("Cannot open file.");
exit (1);
char dum_buffer[1];
}

    fscanf(f, "%i\n", nz);
    fscanf(f, "%i\n", N);

    I[0] = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*(*N+1));

    J[0] = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*(*nz));

    val[0] = (float *)malloc(sizeof(float)*(*nz));

    for(int i=0; i<=*N;i++)
    {

        fscanf(f, "%e ", &(*I)[i]);
        //printf("%e",  &(*I)[i]);

    }
    fscanf(f, "%\n");
    for(int i=0; i<*nz;i++)
    {
        fscanf(f, "%e ", &(*J)[i]);
    }
    fscanf(f, "%\n");

    for(int i=0;i<*nz;i++)
    {
        fscanf(f, "%e ", &(*val)[i]);
    }
    fscanf(f, "%\n");
    return;

    fclose(f);

}

}
```

и фрагмент непосредственно соурса main.cpp:

(.........)

```
int cpu_nz = 0, *cpu_I = NULL, *cpu_J = NULL;
int N = 0;

float *cpu_val = NULL;
```

(..........)

```
read_matrix_from_file(&cpu_I, &cpu_J, &cpu_val, &N, &cpu_nz);
```

(..........)

Comment: @qnek: Вы уверены, что _вся_ эта простыня важна для иллюстрации проблемы? Например, вы уверены, что процедура `genTridiag` нужна нам? Чем больше кода, тем меньше вероятность, что кому-то захочется в нём копаться.

Обязательная ссылка: http://sscce.org/

Comment: ок спасибо буду иметь ввиду :)

Comment: Попробуйте вывести на консоль значения `*nz` и `*N` после чтения их из файла. Посмотрите, такие ли в них значения, как вы ожидаете.

---
Стоп, у вас же указатели `I` и `J` у вас не инициализированы! Поскольку `I == NULL`, то вызов `I[0] = ...;` есть серьёзная ошибка: вы разыменовываете `NULL`-указатель!

Comment: Все я уже нашел проблему всем спасибо :), я прогонял код через gdb, все было ок, I=NULL лиш декларация указателя или масива, затем непосредстевенно в самой функции я запрашиваюпамять так как только там понимаю размер необходимой мне памяте, жсе ето работает потомучто функции я даю указатель на указатель памяти и таким образом выделяемая  память выделяется в стековой рамке main(). 
Проблема была намного глупее просто нер соотетствие форматов я записывал в формате "%е" a некоторые функции из стандартных библиотек ожидали другого.

Answer (score 2):

Одной из Ваших многочисленных ошибок являются неверные параметры в fscanf: там должны быть АДРЕСА переменных N и nz.

Comment: BuilderC: Но там и есть адрес насколько я понимаю....